# Efficiently compute Knuth's up-arrow notation modulus

Tags: optimization, recursion, modulus, exponentiation

I'm already using memoization as a dictionary. Is there anything else I can do? I suspect the for loop might be able to be optimized. For reference I am computing `knuth_arrow(2, 3, 9, 14**8)`

```
memo = {}

def knuth_arrow(a, n, b, m):
    if (a, n, b) in memo:
        return memo[(a, n, b)]

    if n == 0:
        return (a*b) % m

    if n == 1:
        s = pow(a, b, m)
        memo[(a, n, b)] = s
        return s

    if n > 1:
        s = a
        for i in range(b-1):
            s = knuth_arrow(a, n-1, s, m)

        memo[(a, n, b)] = s
        return s
```

Comment: what's up with your `for i in range`? you never make use of the `i`. I don't know knuth, but if you don't need that for loop then just remove it.

Comment: @Catalyst It is for repeating the recursion `b-1` times

Comment: apologies, I see it now `s` = ...thing that uses `s`... my mistake